# Remove middle activities from the stack

Tags: android

How to achieve this behavior:

Lets say i have activity A

Then i start a flow and have activities A,B,C,D

If success in D it will start activity E and the stack will be A,B,C,D,E

What i want here is that the stack would be A,E so B,C,D would be removed from the middle.

Comment: when u want to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Activity> activities =new ArrayList<Activity>();
```

create that and add all your activities to this. whem you need to close them type:

```
activities.get(YOUR_ITEM_INDEX).finish();
```

I thinhk this will solve the problem

let me know about the result

Comment: Yes i was aware of this solution that i keep activities on arraylist, but wanted to know if there's like android way of doing this. Getting that list from some native class instead of keeping it up to date myself.

Comment: all in all this is the clearest and easiest way of all the answers

Comment: I haven't written any native code. So, I don't know. But there must be a way to do this with native code.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good idea. Where this collection should be? application class? If the OS decides to remove an activity because other app needs resources then having a strong references to the activity would prevent the OS to take those resources

Comment: I used broadcast in D to notify any listener activity (**B to be removed in My use case**). Worked like a charm! My start flow was `A>B>C>D`. I had to removed B after some callback received(**if success**)  inside D . So, After sending Broadcast the flow going back was `D >C >A` (Where B finished itself upon broadcast received).

Answer (score 0):

When starting Activity C from B finish B , like Starting D from C finish C ,Starting E now finish D . At last you will only have Activity A and E in stack.

Comment: Yeah, but i want here that only if you press button in D, B and C will finish.

Comment: Its an odd behaviour or against the standrad of Android.If you want to replace simply your views which is the only intention then switch only your views on one activity only .

Answer (score 0):

B,C, D and E should be started with activity from result, and being finished in the OnActivityResult method. Then overriding the back button in the E activity with a finish() (or just finishing the E activity when click a button) would do the trick, when pressing back from E you will move back to A

Answer (score 0):

You just need to decide a history path my activities can take, and call `finish()` when the user performs an action that should 'unwind' my activity stack.

You could also take a look at [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) / [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) or use `android:noHistory="true"` in your *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Comment: activities must be alive until D performs the clearing so cannot use no history flag here.

Comment: Then you just need to call `finish()` on them.. No other way I'm afraid: If D is pressed, finish B and C.

Answer (score 0):

See `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html. Does it suit your needs?

Comment: that flag seems to be only suitable when starting activity which is already in stack.